# Approximation with Bézier curves

Tags: bezier-curve

I have just completed basic research on Bézier curves, mainly focused on the characteristics of Bernstein polynomials and the de Casteljau algorithm. Now I am supposed to approximate $\sin(x)$ and $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ using Bézier curves. How is approximation made using Bézier curves? Thank you.

Comment: Often the method for choosing a Bézier curve to approximate a smooth function is to interpolate values of that function (and possibly its derivatives as well) at selected nodes.  Until you choose a finite interval on which you want to do the approximation, there's not a lot of further advice I can give you.

Comment: So, if I want to do from x=0 to x=pi/2 the Bézier curve should interpolate sin(x) at those points (and the derivatives too), but which others? Thank you.